# Create circular JPopupMenu using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I want to create a `JPopupMenu` that has a few items on it. Instead of rectangular layout of menu I it to open in circular manner and when I click one of the items on menu if it has any sub menu item then it should as a wrapper circular menu again out of the main menu.

I tried but was unable to achieve the requirement.

For reference please see the attached images:

[image: Reference image]

File. Edit and Format are the main menu items. Cut, Copy and Paste are sub-menu items for each.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Circular popupmenu on right click should open with submenue's in swing.

Comment: And, welcome to the wonderful would of custom component creation, including, but not limited to, custom layout management